# Index / Check DB Script question

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, ola-hallengren, dbcc-checkdb

I'm using Ola Hallengren's maintenance scripts and I wanted to see if I could create 2 tables so that it logs integrity checks and index optimizations to different tables.

Answer (score 2):

Logging info to different tables is not possible without rewriting parts of Ola's solution and creating new objects.

By default, you can log the output to the `dbo.CommandLog` table by using `@LogToTable = 'Y'`

You can then query the recent outputs for the integrity checks with this command:

```
SELECT TOP (100) [ID]
      ,[DatabaseName]
      ,[SchemaName]
      ,[ObjectName]
      ,[ObjectType]
      ,[IndexName]
      ,[IndexType]
      ,[StatisticsName]
      ,[PartitionNumber]
      ,[ExtendedInfo]
      ,[Command]
      ,[CommandType]
      ,[StartTime]
      ,[EndTime]
      ,[ErrorNumber]
      ,[ErrorMessage]
  FROM [MNGDB].[dbo].[CommandLog]
  WHERE CommandType = 'DBCC_CHECKDB'
  ORDER BY EndTime desc;
```

You can then change the filter to check the index rebuilds / reorgs by changing the filter to `WHERE CommandType = 'ALTER_INDEX'`.

---

If you really want to change the tables, you could create a copy of the `dbo.CommandLog` table and create `dbo.CommandLogIndex` for example.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CommandLogIndex](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [sysname] NULL,
    [SchemaName] [sysname] NULL,
    [ObjectName] [sysname] NULL,
    [ObjectType] [char](2) NULL,
    [IndexName] [sysname] NULL,
    [IndexType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [StatisticsName] [sysname] NULL,
    [PartitionNumber] [int] NULL,
    [ExtendedInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [Command] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [CommandType] [nvarchar](60) NOT NULL,
    [StartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [ErrorNumber] [int] NULL,
    [ErrorMessage] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_CommandLog2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Afterwards you have to create a new procedure, a copy of the `dbo.CommandExecute` procedure to use the `dbo.CommandLogIndex` table. I use Replace All (`ALT + A`) in SSMS to change the procedure calls.

[image]

As a last step, you could create a copy of the procedure `dbo.IndexOptimize` with the name  `[dbo].[IndexOptimizeLogToTable]` and change the `dbo.CommandExecute` procedure calls to `dbo.CommandExecuteIndex`.

[image]

Afterwards you run the procedure with `@logtotable='Y'`

```
  EXEC [dbo].[IndexOptimizeLogToTable] @databases = 'Test',@logtotable='Y'
```

And you should see the results in the new `dbo.CommandLogIndex` table.